# while (infile) loop only reads the first line from my text file

Tags: c++

Below is a snippet of code I wrote. I have not included all of the code from my functions because I do not have it on my work computer at the moment. I need to cycle through about 10 lines of data, collecting the information and then performing a calculation (calcdata) and outputting to an output text file (senddata). My functions seem to work perfectly, but they don't read past the first line in my text document. I'm able to read first line, calculate first line, and then output the first line.

```
    /*    
    My input file is:

        10  0   S   Y   100
        5   7   S   N   50
        20  4   D   Y   9
        11  2   S   Y   6
        5   1   S   N   120
        31  5   S   N   500
        15  3   D   N   40
        18  4   S   N   50
        12  0   S   N   40
        26  7   D   Y   200

    */

    void getdata (int & adultget, int & childget, char & mealtypeget, char & weekendget, int & depositget, bool & error)

    ifstream infile;
    ofstream outfile;

    int main ()
        {
                infile.open("C:\\input.txt");
                outfile.open("C:\\output.txt");
                while (infile)
                        {
                            getdata(adult, child, mealtype, weekend, deposit, error);
                            calcdata(adult, child, mealtype, weekend, deposit, adultcost, childcost, totalfood, surcharge, tax, tip, totalparty, discount, totaldue);
                            senddata(adultcost, childcost, mealtype, weekend, deposit);
                        }
         infile.close();
         outfile.close();
         return 0;
         }

    void getdata (int & adultget, int & childget, char & mealtypeget, char & weekendget, int & depositget, bool & error)
        {
                infile >> adultget >> childget >> mealtypeget >> weekendget >> depositget;
                .
                .
                .
        }
```

My input file has about 10 lines of data, a mix of int and char. My functions are only reading the first line of the file. Any help?

Comment: What about `while (!infile.eof())`?

Comment: @faranwath: Nope, bad practice. It just checks one of the bad flags.

Comment: The code you showed does not contain the reason of the problem.

Comment: @MM. Aren't those set when EOF is hit?

Comment: @faranwath: If any error occures, it will not set EOF true.

Comment: I see, thanks for pointing this out. Does hitting EOF set one of `badbit` or `failbit`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the stream in right place. Change `getdata` which returns a `bool`:

```
bool getdata (...)
{
   bool ok = infile >> adultget >> ...;

   ...

   return ok;
}
```

and the loop should be like:

```
while (getdata(adult, child, ... ))
{

    calcdata(adult, child, ...);
    senddata(adultcost, childcost, ...);
}
```

Comment: So change my getdata function from void to bool?

Comment: @user2990884: Yes, In my opinion it's a good way to return reading status.

Answer (score 0):

Your getdata() method changes local copies of adult, child, etc...  You need to pass the arguments to it by reference if you expect the values back in main to change.

i.e. void getdata(int & adultget, int & childget  .. and so on

Comment: Sorry, I forgot that I actually did that in my original code. I retyped this from work. Editing my original post now.

Answer (score 0):

I can only guess that the problem is that some error occured when you read data for example there is maybe an incorrect format of data in the file.

Comment: Vlad thank you for answering. When I am home in about 1 hour I will paste my entire code.